# caption package doesn't recognize font=doublespacing?

Tags: captions, line-spacing

The journal I'm targetting requires "doublespaced" figure captions, and posts like these

http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=4187

made me try out the `caption` package. I grabbed it from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption) and looking at its doc (p. 10) made me try the `font=doublespacing` option, via a `\usepackage[font=doublespacing]{caption}` line in my preamble. But doing so generates an unknown key error:

```
! Package keyval Error: doublespacing undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
l.448 \ProcessOptionsWithKV{caption}

this is using  pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4) (format=pdflatex 
2006.12.10), via LyX v2.0.3.
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include the MWE directly after the existing content. Also include the contents of your `.log` file (after `*File List*`) when you include `\listfiles` in your document preamble. This will give the community an indication of the packages you load and their age (and whether they are outdated or not).

Answer (score 10):

You must load the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package to use `caption`'s `doublespacing` option .

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[font=doublespacing]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut
    purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
    Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
    consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, setspace doesn't fix it for me?

Comment: @rik Then you must be doing something different, and you should add a minimal working example to your question that shows the problematic behaviour.

Comment: check out: http://pastie.org/3851166

Comment: @rik Compiles fine for me (after I added the `demo` option to the `graphicx` package).

Comment: @rik Try to remove all auxiliary files and compile again.

Comment: started from a clean directory; still same error.  fyi, with the "\usepackage[font=doublespacing]{caption}" line, it doesn't even create a .aux file?!  comment out this line, and .aux created, everything else too.  very odd...

Comment: One need at least version 3.1 (2007/09/01) of the `caption` package for `setspace` support. Your version of the `caption` package is definitely older than that, as I can see from the error message. (\ProcessOptionsWithKV isn't used anymore since v3.0l)